# How to suppress INFO messages for spark-sql running on EMR?

Tags: log4j, apache-spark, emr

I'm running Spark on EMR as described in [Run Spark and Spark SQL on Amazon Elastic MapReduce](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/4926593393724923):

> This tutorial walks you through installing and operating Spark, a fast
>   and general engine for large-scale data processing, on an Amazon EMR
>   cluster. You will also create and query a dataset in Amazon S3 using
>   Spark SQL, and learn how to monitor Spark on an Amazon EMR cluster
>   with Amazon CloudWatch.

I'm trying to suppress the `INFO` logs by editing `$HOME/spark/conf/log4j.properties` to no avail.

Output looks like:

```
$ ./spark/bin/spark-sql
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/.versions/2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/.versions/spark-1.1.1.e/lib/spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2014-12-14 20:59:01,819 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1009)) - mapred.input.dir.recursive is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive
2014-12-14 20:59:01,825 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1009)) - mapred.max.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
2014-12-14 20:59:01,825 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1009)) - mapred.min.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
2014-12-14 20:59:01,825 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(1009)) - mapred.min.split.size.per.rack is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack
```

How to suppress the INFO messages above?

Comment: what is the java package for Spark?

Comment: Some progress:  Doing a  
`./spark/bin/spark-shell --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.debug"`

Allows me to pass a JVM option and see that it's a log4j.properties file somewhere in a jar.  


Doing  
`./spark/bin/spark-shell --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/hadoop/spark/conf/log4j.properties"`

Seems to work, although this seems awfully clunky

Answer (score 19):

You can also just add the configuration option at cluster creation, if you know you want to suppress logging for a new EMR cluster.

EMR accepts configuration options as JSON, which you can enter directly into the AWS console, or pass in via a file when using the CLI.

In this case, in order to change the log level to `WARN`, here's the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "classification": "spark-log4j",
    "properties": {"log4j.rootCategory": "WARN, console"}
  }
]
```

In the console, you'd add this in the first creation step:

[image: configuration in the AWS Console]

Or if you're creating the cluster using the CLI:

```
aws emr create-cluster <options here> --configurations config_file.json
```

You can read more [in the EMR documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html).

Answer (score 16):

I was able to do this by editing `$HOME/spark/conf/log4j.properties` as desired, and calling `spark-sql` with `--driver-java-options` as follows:

```
./spark/bin/spark-sql --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/hadoop/spark/conf/log4j.properties"
```

I could verify that the correct file was being used by adding `-Dlog4j.debug` to the options:

```
./spark/bin/spark-sql --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/hadoop/spark/conf/log4j.properties"
```

Comment: in Spark 3, the log config file is at `/etc/spark/conf.dist/log4j.properties`

Answer (score 6):

spark-sql --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///home/hadoop/conf/log4j.properties"

`cat conf/log4j.properties`

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=WARN
```